# Floats in IE not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get my divs to float correctly in IE. They look great in Chrome and Firefox, but IE chews up the code. You can see the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vlyandra/kEm3R/ Basically, the image div does not line up horizontally with the entry div, and the table at the bottom (despite having a max width) is not resizing. The code to generate the posts is below:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="bordered centered">
    <p class="negative-margin alignleft header"><?php the_title(); ?></p><p class="negative-margin alignright date"><?php the_date(); ?></p><div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content negative-margin">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):?>
            <div id="entry-left">
                <?php   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
                echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
                echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large'); 
                echo '</a>';?>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-right">
                <?php the_content( __( 'More <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'huckleberry' ) ); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'huckleberry' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            </div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="entry-right">
                <table class="fixed-height fixed-width">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="valigned"><h3 class="date">Details</h3>
                            <?php the_field('details');?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="valigned">
                            <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');?>">
                                <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="valigned">
                            <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'tertiary-image');?>">
                                <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'tertiary-image'); endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="valigned">
                            <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'fourth-image');?>">
                                <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'fourth-image'); endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php the_content( __( 'More <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'huckleberry' ) ); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'huckleberry' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing it. Can you send a link to your site?

Also, have you tried applying .alignleft to the images?